# Why aren't Rogue One's event/characters ever referenced later?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, continuity

The events of *Rogue One* are of vital importance in the history and the subsequent success of the Rebel Alliance. I won't go into the details here, we know that the successful mission to steal the Death Star's plans allow the Rebels to discover and exploit its weak spot.

At the same time, the characters involved with this mission could be safely described as true heroes, having sacrificed even themselves in order to accomplish their mission.

**In-universe, is there a reason why not the events nor the characters are ever referenced again?**

The secrecy of the mission itself was a vital aspect in order to accomplish it, so one could argue that publicly celebrating those that were involved could be harmful (if you have secret information about your enemy, you don't want them to know that you do).

But in the movie ending, we learn that the Empire is aware that the Rebels posses the plans, and that a Rebel commando was present and successful on Scarif, so the secrecy is no more a factor to be taken in consideration.

**In-universe, why aren't the heroes that made possible the ultimate Rebel victory referenced, celebrated, or otherwise remembered in later times? What is the reason to still keep the secret?**

Comment: Celebrated by who? When?

Comment: By the Rebel Alliance, after their succesful mission.

Comment: Erm, the next time we catch up with the Rebels it's a few minutes after everyone got killed and the fleet was scattered

Comment: I don't mean *immediately* after those events. I mean *at any given point in a later time*. Out-of universe it is clear why, the other movies were filed decades before, but in-universe, it seem strange that such great heroes never receive their due praise.

Comment: Lots of people were involved. They used Bodhi's call-sign later on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How do you know they are not celebrated? We don’t see everything that happens in a movie. We only see the action.

In the final scene of Episode IV, we see a lot of people gathered in a celebration ceremony. We only catch about 60 seconds of that ceremony, but I am sure that a part of that ceremony we didn’t see was a speaker recounting the heroics of Rogue One, probably with a PowerPoint slideshow running in the background showing the faces of the heroes who died.

Comment: The same can be said about Star Wars - Rebels.

Comment: Also retcon's are a pita.... At the battle of endorsed APPARENTLY Asoka and bridgers were alive

Comment: Battle of endorsed?

Comment: @suchiuomizu Battle of Endor (autocorrect, I’m sure)

Comment: @Naib - Ezra was lost...somewhere. Ahsoka...who knows?

Comment: @Adamant go watch "Family Reunion and Farewell". Right at the end, set after the battle of endor Ahsoka is there to go find Ezra. Ezra is lost, Ahsoka isn't

Comment: @Naib - Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @Adamant maybe... more confused with "ahsoka ... who knows". Her whereabouts are known from the narrative